# Waiting for page to load - UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

So I have a Windows 10 app with a XAML page that has a `Pivot` item and the default behavior of a `Pivot` is that whenever you navigate to the page with the `Pivot`, the first item on the `Pivot` gets selected right away. What I want to do is execute some code *before* the first item in `Pivot` runs.

**Code in Context**

```
public sealed partial class ContentFrame : Page
{
    private IMobileServiceTable<News> NewsItems = App.MobileService.GetTable<News>();

    private List<News> AllNews;

    private List<News> Windows = new List<News>();
    private List<News> Apple = new List<News>();
    private List<News> Google = new List<News>();
    private List<News> Other = new List<News>();
    private List<News> Top = new List<News>();

    private string WeekID;

    public ContentFrame()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        WeekID = e.Parameter as string;
        AllNews = await NewsItems.Where(News => News.Week == WeekID).ToListAsync();
        separateContent();
    }

    private void separateContent()
    {
        foreach (News item in AllNews)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Tag);
            if (item.Tag == "Windows")
                Windows.Add(item);
            else if (item.Tag == "Apple")
                Apple.Add(item);
            else if (item.Tag == "Google")
                Google.Add(item);
            else if (item.Tag == "Other")
                Other.Add(item);
            else
                Top.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void Tags_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IntroHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        WindowsHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        AppleHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        GoogleHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        OtherHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;

        switch (Tags.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                IntroHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
                StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(TopNewsPage), Top);
                break;
            case 1:
                WindowsHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
                StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(OtherNews), Windows);
                break;
            case 2:
                AppleHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
                StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(OtherNews), Apple);
                break;
            case 3:
                GoogleHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
                StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(OtherNews), Google);
                break;
            case 4:
                OtherHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
                StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(OtherNews), Other);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Code line relating to issue:

> StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(TopNewsPage), Top);

This executes too soon, and I want to wait until the `separateContent();` method is done *before* I allow the app to navigate the `Pivot` control on my XAML layout. If I don't, the parameter passed in (`Top`) is going to be null/empty and my app will throw an exception as soon as I navigate to `TopNewsPage`.

How can I do this?

I understand that the way I am making my app isn't the nicest one (MVVM is something that I am looking to explore in the future) but this is my first app and I really just want to get this to work. I have explored a bit with `Task`, but nothing seems to help my cause because the `Pivot` navigation is too fast.

Comment: Why not call `separateContent();` after `InitializeComponent()`?

Comment: Good question. I need the `WeekID` passed in the parameter on the `OnNavigatedTo` method before I call `separateContent();`, so it doesn't work for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I do not consider this to be a good solution to my problem, but it is one that works.

**Here is what I did:**

1. Added a check for `Top.Count` in `Tags_SelectionChanged` so that nothing runs if that `List` is empty.
2. Added two lines of code in the end of `separateContent();` so that I execute the first `Pivot` item once `Top` has items in it.

If you have a better way to do this, please share it!

```
    private void separateContent()
    {
        foreach (News item in AllNews)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Tag);
            if (item.Tag == "Windows")
                Windows.Add(item);
            else if (item.Tag == "Apple")
                Apple.Add(item);
            else if (item.Tag == "Google")
                Google.Add(item);
            else if (item.Tag == "Other")
                Other.Add(item);
            else
                Top.Add(item);
        }
        IntroHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
        StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(TopNewsPage), Top);
    }

    private void Tags_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Top.Count < 6)
            return;
        IntroHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        WindowsHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        AppleHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        GoogleHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        OtherHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;

        switch (Tags.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                IntroHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
                StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(TopNewsPage), Top);
                break;
            case 1:
                WindowsHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
                StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(OtherNews), Windows);
                break;
            case 2:
                AppleHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
                StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(OtherNews), Apple);
                break;
            case 3:
                GoogleHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
                StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(OtherNews), Google);
                break;
            case 4:
                OtherHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
                StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(OtherNews), Other);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you've mentioned that you mainly want `WeekID` to have a value first before you want the `Tags_SelectionChanged` to work and `WeekID` is set on the `OnNavigatedTo` event. I'd suggest doing nothing on the `Tags_SelectionCHanged` event so long as `WeekID` is not yet set.

Try:

```
private void Tags_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(WeekID))
        return;

    IntroHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
    WindowsHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
    AppleHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
    GoogleHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
    OtherHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;

    switch (Tags.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            IntroHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
            StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(TopNewsPage), Top);
            break;
        case 1:
            WindowsHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
            StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(OtherNews), Windows);
            break;
        case 2:
            AppleHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
            StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(OtherNews), Apple);
            break;
        case 3:
            GoogleHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
            StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(OtherNews), Google);
            break;
        case 4:
            OtherHead.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
            StoryContent.Navigate(typeof(OtherNews), Other);
            break;
    }
}
```

In case this works for you, you might want to set `WeekID` to null or empty on the event before you navigate to another page or when the page closes since I don't know if `ContentFrame` will retain the value for `WeekID` in such events. Just a tip.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this doesn't help solve my problem. First, I actually tried `if(Top.Count == 0) return;`, instead of verifying `WeekID` but in the end what that does is, yes, avoid the exception but it doesn't load the page. I have to switch `Pivot` items to something else and then back to load `TopNews.xaml` correctly. I need something that stops and waits the default navigation until `Top.Count != 0`. Your solution doesn't wait and it requires the user to reload the `Pivot` item.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: https://github.com/baskren/P42.Uno.AsyncNavigation/tree/main

Something to consider:  If you could pre-load a page, then you could async / await until the page pre-loading is complete before displaying it.  But wait, you say, UWP Navigate doesn't allow pages to be pre-loaded - and it's not async / await!

True, but there is a way around this.  First, consider that `Page` inherits from `FrameworkElement`.  This means a `Page` can be a child of a `Grid` or the content of a `ContentPresenter`.  Here's a quick experiment that shows this:

**ChildPage.xaml (the page I want to pre-load before presenting):**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="NestedPagesExperiment.Shared.ChildPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:NestedPagesExperiment.Shared"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Children>
                <TextBlock Text="I AM THE CHILD PAGE CONTENT!!!!" />
            </Grid.Children>
        </Grid>
    </Page.Content>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml (the hosting page - to which a pre-loaded `ChildPage` will be added):**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="NestedPagesExperiment.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:NestedPagesExperiment"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Content>

        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.Children>
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="20"
                    FontSize="30"
                    Text="Hello, world!" />
                <Button
                    x:Name="_button"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Click="OnButtonClick"
                    Content="Add Content" />
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="_contentPresenter" Grid.Row="2" />
            </Grid.Children>
        </Grid>
    </Page.Content>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs (the code behind):**

```cs
using NestedPagesExperiment.Shared;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace NestedPagesExperiment
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var content = new ChildPage();
            _contentPresenter.Content = content;
        }
    }
}
```

But wait, you say, I still want to have page transitions!  Take a look at how Xamarin.Forms pulls this off:

First, Xamarin has a page container (`FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper`) that host's the dynamically generated page.
**FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ContentPresenter Name="Root" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    </ContentPresenter>
</Page>
```

Notice the following:

- It's very light weight, so there's nothing here that wouldn't load quickly using traditional UWP Page navigation.
- There is a `ContentPresenter` on line 10. As we'll see, this is where the pre-loaded content will be placed.

Just as important, look at the code behind:

```cs
    public sealed partial class FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
    {
        internal static Dictionary<Guid, ContentPage> Pages = new Dictionary<Guid, ContentPage>();

        public FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            if (e.Parameter == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot navigate to {nameof(FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper)} without "
                    + $"providing a {nameof(Xamarin.Forms.Page)} identifier.");
            }

            // Find the page instance in the dictionary and then discard it so we don't prevent it from being collected
            var key = (Guid)e.Parameter;
            var page = Pages[key];
            Pages.Remove(key);

            // Convert that page into a FrameWorkElement we can display in the ContentPresenter
            FrameworkElement frameworkElement = page.CreateFrameworkElement();

            if (frameworkElement == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not find or create a renderer for the Page {page}");
            }

            Root.Content = frameworkElement;
        }
    }
```

And, to complete the puzzle, we need one more piece - an extension method:

```cs
        internal static bool Navigate(this Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame frame, ContentPage page, Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.NavigationTransitionInfo infoOverride)
        {

            if (page == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(page));
            }

            Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

            FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper.Pages.Add(id, page);
            if (infoOverride != null)
                return frame.Navigate(typeof(FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper), id, infoOverride);

            return frame.Navigate(typeof(FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper), id);
        }
```

So, when it's time to navigate to a new page, here's is what Xamarin.Forms is doing:

1. their Navigate extension function takes the pre-generated page and puts it into a static dictionary (`FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper.Pages`), keyed to a freshly generated GUID.
2. The UWP `frame.Navigate(Type, object)` method is called with the very lightweight `FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper` type and the GUID key, generated above, as arguments.
3. UWP instantiates and displays a new instance of `FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper`.
4. UWP call's `OnNavigatedTo` on the `FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper` instance - and includes the GUID key in the argument.
5. the `FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper` instance uses the GUID key to pull the pre-loaded page content from the `Pages` static dictionary.
6. `FormsEmbeddedPageWrapper` sets the `Content` of its `ContentPresenter` to the pre-loaded page content retrieved from the `Pages` static dictionary.

This approach preserves the use of UWP page transition animations AND allows for  page content to be pre-loaded.

Although Xamarin.Forms code snippets were used to explain this approach, there is nothing in this approach that could not be used in run-of-the-mill UWP apps.